# how to authenticate encrypted password at LDAP server

Tags: passwords, ldap, at-command, encryption

How to authenticate encrypted password at LDAP server

Comment: You need to provide some kind of better detail, than you currently have now.  What LDAP server?  In what application/framework/language?  Your question is impossible to answer or address as currently written.

Comment: I disagree. It doesn't make any difference what LDAP server. The language doesn't make much difference either. The library does in that some i.e. JNDI expose the bind operation as 'reconnect', but that can be covered in a proper answer. For a counter-example that refutes your final assertion see below.

Answer (score 0):

In general the answer is to attempt an LDAP bind operation with those credentials. Note that this is not the same as a JNDI bind, it is a JNDI/LDAP reconnect.